# Error when extracting Steiner Tree using networkx.algorithms.approximation.steinertree.steiner_tree

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, networkx, shapefile, qgis

I exported two sets of data:

1. Road Data that I exported as a .shp file from QGIS
2. A point layer of nodes (long, lat) that I exported as a .shp file from QGIS

I wanted to use the networkx library to extract the Steiner Tree connecting all nodes along the given roads. In order to do this I wrote the following code on a jupyter notebook:

```
import networkx as nx #importing the NetworkX library
Road = nx.read_shp('proj_data/roads/cmbRoads.shp') #Reading Road Data 
Base = nx.read_shp('proj_data/bs/bsSnapped.shp') #Reading Terminal Node Data
nodes = list(Base.nodes) #Creating list of terminal nodes
from networkx.algorithms import approximation as ax
st_tree = ax.steinertree.steiner_tree(Road,nodes,weight='length')
```

All lines of code up to the Steiner tree extraction have executed without any issue. I recieved the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NetworkXNotImplemented                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-99884445086e> in <module>
      1 from networkx.algorithms import approximation as ax
----> 2 st_tree = ax.steinertree.steiner_tree(Road,nodes,weight='length')

<c:\users\nandula\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-849> in steiner_tree(G, terminal_nodes, weight)

c:\users\nandula\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py in _not_implemented_for(not_implement_for_func, *args, **kwargs)
     80             raise nx.NetworkXNotImplemented(msg)
     81         else:
---> 82             return not_implement_for_func(*args, **kwargs)
     83     return _not_implemented_for
     84 

<c:\users\nandula\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-848> in steiner_tree(G, terminal_nodes, weight)

c:\users\nandula\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py in _not_implemented_for(not_implement_for_func, *args, **kwargs)
     78         if match:
     79             msg = 'not implemented for %s type' % ' '.join(graph_types)
---> 80             raise nx.NetworkXNotImplemented(msg)
     81         else:
     82             return not_implement_for_func(*args, **kwargs)

NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for directed type
```

Any insight into what I might be doing wrong here or an alernative way in which I might accomplish this (geopandas maybe) would be helpful.

NOTE: I didn't use the processing toolbox within QGIS itself as I need to run this code on a CentOS server due to insufficient RAM on my personal computer (the data set is quite large).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your graph created from the QGIS data seems to be a directed graph and the algorithm is only implemented for undirected graphs.

I would suggest, that you check which type of graph your `Road` graph is by using `nx.is_directed` and `nx.is_multigraphical`.

You can cast to an undirected graph `undirected_roads = nx.Graph(Road)` and afterwards call the algorithm `ax.steinertree.steiner_tree(undirected_roads,nodes,weight='length')`. 
However, you will loose some information depending on how asymmetric your original graph is.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you

Comment: I end up with the following:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: Have you the type of the edge attributes `'length'`? Maybe they are strings instead of floats or ints

Comment: I get "G is not a connected graph. metric_closure is not defined."

Comment: If it is not connected, you probably want to work on the largest connected component.